# How to insert a null value from php variable to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to set a field to null value by php variable.
I'm working with Laravel eloquent.

```
             if($request->sectionId=='NULL'){
               $sectionId=NULL;
             }else{
                $sectionId=$request->sectionId;
             }
            $question= new Question;
            $question->sectionid=$sectionId;
```

It returns me error :
Incorrect integer value: 'NUll' for column `farsifor_m`.`questions`.`sectionid` at row 1 (SQL: insert into `questions` (`formid`, `questionType`, `order`, `sectionid`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, shortAnswer, 1, NUll, 2021-05-08 18:51:24, 2021-05-08 18:51:24))"

Comment: Why does it have `NUll` instead of something like `NULL`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a typo in the value of `$request->sectionId` - 'NUll' instead of 'NULL'.